# Nested Selectors in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have trouble getting nested Selectors to work as described in the documentation of Scrapy (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Here's what I got:

```
sel = Selector(response)
level3fields = sel.xpath('//ul/something/*')

for element in level3fields:
    site = element.xpath('/span').extract()
```

When I print out "element" in the loop I get `< Selector xpath='stuff seen above' data="u'< span class="something">text< /span>>`

Now I got two problems:

1. Firstly, within the element, there should also be an "a"-node (as in `<a href`), but it doesn't show up in the print out, only if I extract it directly, then it does show up. Is that just a printing error or doesn't the "element-Selector" hold the a-node (without extraction)
2. when I print out "site" above, it should show a list with the span-nodes. However, it doesn't, it only prints out an empty list.

I tried a combination of changes (multiple to no slashes and stars (*) in different places), but none of it brought me any closer.

Essentially, I just want to get a nested Selector which gives me the span-node in the second step (the loop).

Anyone got any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding your first question, it's just a print "error". `__repr__` and `__str__` methods on Selectors only print the first 40 characters of the data (element represented as HTML/XML or text content). See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/selector/unified.py#L143

In your loop on `level3fields` you should use relative XPath expressions. Using `/span` will look for `span` elements directly under the root node, that's not what you want I guess.

Try this:

```
sel = Selector(response)
level3fields = sel.xpath('//ul/something')

for element in level3fields:
    site = element.xpath('.//span').extract()
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, this solved my problem. I think the main issue was forgetting the dot ("."), which indicates, that I have to refer to the current node.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to add a "." in front of all my XPaths to be safe