# In Scrapy, how to nest an Xpath expression with only a call to /text()

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Running the Scrapy shell for the following website,

http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/shareit-technologies-co-ltd/shareit-connect-transfer/shareit-3-0-38_ww-release/shareit-3-0-38_ww-android-apk-download/

I'm trying to get the lines of text from this 'APK details' area:

[image]

I have the following selector for the `div` containing the text:

```
In [91]: response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]').extract()
Out[91]: [u'<div class="appspec-value">Version: 3.0.38_ww (4030038)<br>arm <br><span class="wrapText">Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps</span>\n<br>2,239 downloads </div>']
```

Note that the line with "Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps" is inside a `<span>` element, whereas the rest are not. I'd therefore like to use this selector twice: to get the `/text()` and the span. To avoid code repetition, I'd like to give this selector a name and concatenate it with others later.

Therefore, I tried assigning the name

```
In [95]: apk_details = response.xpath('//*[@title="APK details"]/following-sibling::*[@class="appspec-value"]')
```

but if I do `apk_details.xpath('/text()').extract()`, I get `None`. I also tried

```
In [107]: apk_details.xpath('.//*/text()').extract()
Out[107]: [u'Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps']
```

following [Nested Selectors in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631819/nested-selectors-in-scrapy), but this gives me the "Package" line and not the lines before.

How can I next a selector with a simple (`/text()`) call?

Comment: Did you try `apk_details.xpath('.//text()').extract()`?

Comment: Andersson pretty much answered the question here - `//` is notation for selecting any descendant of the node, in turn `//text()` means any descendants text() value. `.` is there to indicate that you are selecting from current node instead of root node since xpath does not isolate it's nodes (i.e. you can access any part of the document from any node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as given by [Andersson](http://%20Andersson) and confirmed and explained by [Granitosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3737009/granitosaurus), is

```
In [109]: apk_details.xpath('.//text()').extract()
Out[109]: 
[u'Version: 3.0.38_ww (4030038)',
 u'arm ',
 u'Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps',
 u'\n',
 u'2,239 downloads ']
```

Interestingly, this includes the `Package` line, even though this was not included by calling `/text()` on the original Xpath expression. This is because the `//` refers to any descendant including the `<span>` element. This is actually what I would prefer, though.

Answer (score 0):

please see the following lines if helpful.

```
In [120]: response.xpath('//[@id="file"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]//text()').extract()

Out[120]: 
[u'Version: 3.0.38_ww (4030038)',
 u'arm ',
 u'Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps',
 u'\n',
 u'2,239 downloads ']

In [121]: vd=response.xpath('//*
    [@id="file"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]//text()').extract()

In [122]: for v in vd:
     ...:     print v
     ...:     
Output:

    Version: 3.0.38_ww (4030038)
    arm 
    Package: com.lenovo.anyshare.gps
    2,239 download
```